# Why my APP does not support Samsung Galaxy Note 3

Tags: android, google-play, apk, samsung-mobile

I have an application published on google play, the app works fine for all mobile devices and Tab 7 and Tab 10, but it can't be visible for Samsung Not 3.

Here is the manifest file:

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                  android:smallScreens="true" 
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"/>
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all small size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all normal size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

</compatible-screens>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

If I add this line, do you thik it will work?

```
<screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="480"/>
```

Comment: Why are you listing all of those manually? Are you deliberately not supporting xxhdpi?

Comment: Because it was not working without it, so I tried to put this and still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should include android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" in your screenDensity because im sure Samsung Note 3 has that screen density

Comment: but its already android:anyDensity="true" , is it so to right "xxhdpi" ?

Comment: yeah but <compatible-screens> will overide it. and i dont think you need all that just remove them all include supportScreens and try again